# BOSS RC-505MK2: OSC BOT and Vocoder effects not working

Tags: stereo, effects, mono, looping, vocoder

I’ve been wanting to experiment with the different FX, specifically OSC BOT, whenever it is selected, my microphone output goes dead.

As I am selecting a different effects and speaking into the microphone to test I can hear my voice changing in real time with many of them but as soon as I hit OSC BOT and VOCODER (there are a couple others as well that give the same issue), nothing.....

Tried adjusting the output volume and literally nothing comes out until I turn the effect off, switch to another effect.

Running newest firmware (1.21)

Here is my set up if this helps:

AKG PRO D5S Dynamic Mic plugged into Mic 1 via XLR

Y cable going from MASTER L/R on Boss to 1/4in Mic input on Bose S1 pro

OUTPUT>SETUP>STEREO LINK>MAIN set to ON (this was on off by default and I couldn’t hear any Mic output on my Bose until I turned it on)

Hoping this isn’t a defective unit. Hopefully it’s just a settings or output issue?

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts....